# Can Galera handle 600-4500 databases?

Tags: mysql, galera

I have over 600Dbs and want to switch from traditional replication to Galera Cluster, will like to know if Galera can handle 600-4500 DBs.

Thanks..

Comment: You already received an answer to this - "600 dbs -- ugly for other reasons, but it should not matter to Galera." - in your other thread, which you even acknowledged by saying thanks. Was that not sufficient?

Comment: Yes, i  kind of need some more light on "ugly for other reasons".What are the other reasons??.

Comment: That many databases is *often* a sign of someone doing something weird, like a separate database for each page's comments or something.

Comment: I still not get the reason, can Galera handle plus 600DBs in production without any problems??

Comment: You already have that answer. "Yes, but it's possible having 600-4500 databases means you're structuring your app wrong."

Comment: Tanks  Ceejayoz, also what about the number of nodes??..lets say i use 9 nodes as oppose to  5 nodes, will i have more performance and scalability with 9 nodes cluster as oppose to 5 nodes??.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. You might be better suited with asynchronous replicated slaves instead of more nodes in the cluster. You might consider hiring a consultant versed in this. I'd recommend https://www.percona.com/

Comment: Galera performance flattens out, or possibly declines, after about 5 nodes.  Would a 3-node cluster with readonly Slave(s) hanging off each be a viable topology for you?  _Virtually any_ number of such Slaves can be handled.  (In a single tier, 20 per node should work; in 2 tiers, hundreds.)